# Is there a simple way for moving wordpress site from abc.com to xyz.abc.com?

Tags: wordpress

I's like to know a simple and effective way for moving a wordpress site from supposed abc.com to sub-domain xyz.abc.com. There is also an explained method in http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of plugins available that will automate the process for you.
I've used BackupBuddy (https://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) a lot in the past which is a premium option. There are a lot of backup plugins that will do the the trick - the first to come up in a quick Google search: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of is using [WP-CLI: Command line interface for WordPress](https://wp-cli.org/) But you'll need to have have access to a shell.

If you don't have access to a shell then on http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress they recommend

1. Use the Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin if you can access your WP Admin Dashboard.
2. Use the Better Search Replace plugin if you can access your WP Admin Dashboard.

To have access to the wp-admin on the new url you'll probably have to add in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL for more details.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to export the database to a SQL file - e.g. using phpMyAdmin - and use your favourite text editor to find & replace all mentions of 'abc.com' by 'xyz.abc.com'. Then you can import the SQL file again.

For me that works faster and easier than any plugin I've tried.

Good luck!